# Why is the bulk API 2.0's successfulResults endpoint returning blank values in the fields from the original CSV request?

Tags: bulk-api

I'm starting to use the Bulk API 2.0 and am seeing an unexpected result from successfulResults.

I'm uploading this CSV for an upsert operation (for this post I replaced my prefix with 'prefix'.):

```
prefix__case__c,prefix__contact__c,prefix__score__c,prefix__comment__c,prefix__questionid__c,prefix__surveysent__c,prefix__surveyresponded__c,prefix__segment__c,prefix__dontcontact__c,prefix__npscalc__c,prefix__questioncontactid__c,prefix__tag__c
"","0037F00000CTNFVQA5","5","Expensive","7","2017-08-06T22:17:09+00:00","2017-08-10T06:13:42+00:00","Silver","","-1","7","Price"
```

The operation works -- the record is inserted -- but I'm surprised by what successfulResults returns:

```
"sf__Id","sf__Created",prefix__case__c,prefix__comment__c,prefix__contact__c,prefix__dontcontact__c,prefix__npscalc__c,prefix__questioncontactid__c,prefix__questionid__c,prefix__score__c,prefix__segment__c,prefix__surveyresponded__c,prefix__surveysent__c,prefix__tag__c
"a017F000009NCKxQAO","true","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

[The documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_job_successful_results.htm) that the responses includes "Field data for the row that was provided in the original job data upload request", but you can see that all these fields were returned as empty strings.  This makes it hard for us to reconcile the sf__Id values with the external IDs we sent, particularly because the documentation also warns "The order of records in the response is not guaranteed to match the ordering of records in the original job data."

Why might this be happening?  I was unable to find any other reports of this behavior.

Also, this problem does not happen for the insert operation, only upsert.